# Django passing parameter

Tags: django

I have a page which list, a list of volunteers from the volunteer_list table.

Volunteer_list table contains the following fields,
Voluntter name
Volunteer position name
Date created

Now from this page-Mainpage I need to pass the Volunteer position name to the next page-Contactpage.The volunteer position field is 50 byte field.

How do I define my view for the Contactpage and how can I access the passed field in my contactpage?

volunteer_list.html

```
<tr>
        <th colspan=4 align="left"><label for="id_Volposition">Volunteer Position:</label></th>
        <th colspan=.5 align="left"><a href="/signups/new/{{ v.position }}" class="username" <u>{{ v.volposition }}</u></a></th>
<tr> <td colspan="2" height="2" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td> </tr>
</tr>
```

If you notice here, i will be calling the signups/new page, with v.position being passed as the parameter..I need to know the following, 1.How will urls.py be defined for signups/new page to access the v.position parameter 2. How will I access the parameter in signups/new page

My URLS.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   (r'^new/$',                           sfp.view),
   (r'^volunteer/$',     volunteer_page),
   (r'^vollist/$', volunteer_list),
   (r'^volcont/$', volunteer_contact)
)
```

The new/$ calls the sfp.view..Its a function in my views.py..That view will basically render a html page that collects all the information.

I need to know how to pass the parameter "position" to this function?

This is a existing piece of code..

If its a direct call like the one given in the tutorial, I dont have any problems.

def detail(request, poll_id):

- Code for sfp.view

views.py

```
    sfp = SimpleFormProcessing(
        form_class=VolunteerSignupForm,
        form_2_model=volunteersignupform_2_model,
        form_template='signups/create_contact_form.dmpl',
        email_template='signups/response_email.dmpl',
        email_html_template='signups/response_email_html.dmpl',
        email_subject='Vibha Volunteer Signup',
        email_sender='volunteer@vibha.org',
        redirect_url='/signups/thanks/',
        do_captcha=True)



code for simpleformprocessing:


    class SimpleFormProcessing:

        def __init__(self, form_class, form_2_model, form_template,
                email_template, email_subject, email_sender, redirect_url,
                do_captcha=False, record_ip_addr=False, email_html_template=None):
            self.form_class = form_class
            self.form_2_model = form_2_model
            self.form_template = form_template
            self.email_template = email_template
            self.email_html_template = email_html_template
            self.email_subject = email_subject
            self.email_sender = email_sender
            self.redirect_url = redirect_url
            self.do_captcha = do_captcha
            self.record_ip_addr = record_ip_addr

        def view(self, request, initial={}):
            Form = self.form_class
            if self.do_captcha:
                Form = form_with_captcha(Form, request)
            if self.record_ip_addr:
                Form = form_with_ipaddress(Form, request)
            if request.method == 'POST':
                # Try processing the form
                if self.do_captcha and not accepts_cookies(request):
                    return our_flatpage('Please enable cookies and try again.')
                else:
                    form = Form(request.POST)
                    if form.is_valid():
                        # The form is correct, process it
                        model = self.form_2_model(form)
                        if self.email_template:
                            text_content = render_to_string(self.email_template, {'model': model})
                            recipients = model.emailRecipients()
                            try:
                                bcc_recipients = model.emailBCCRecipients()
                            except:
                                bcc_recipients = None
                            msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(self.email_subject, text_content, self.email_sender,

                                recipients, bcc_recipients)

                        if self.email_html_template:
                            html_content = render_to_string(self.email_html_template, {'model': model})
                            msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

                        msg.send()

                    return HttpResponseRedirect(self.redirect_url)
                else:
                    # Show the form with errors
                    return render_to_response(self.form_template, {'form': form})
        else:
            # Show the empty form
            form = Form(initial=initial)
            if self.do_captcha:
```

Comment: This questions is overly vague. What have you tried? Can you show us some code?

Comment: <tr>
        <th colspan=4 align="left"><label for="id_Volposition">Volunteer Position:</label></th>
        <th colspan=.5 align="left"><a href="/signups/new/{{ v.position }}" class="username" <u>{{ v.volposition }}</u></a></th>
<tr> <td colspan="2" height="2" style="display:none">&nbsp;</td> </tr>
</tr>
If you notice here, i will be calling the signups/new page, with v.position being passed as the parameter..I need to know the following, 1.How will urls.py be defined for signups/new page to access the v.position parameter  2. How will I access the parameter in signups/new page

Comment: Please edit your question and place the code inside there. It's unreadable within a comment. Make sure you indent the entire section by at least 4 spaces so it's in a code block.

Comment: @Paragon: I have made the changes as per your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView

url(r'^/signups/new/?P(<position>\w+)/$', TemplateView.as_view(
    template_name='relative_path_to_template')),
```

The class TemplateView is a simple view that will allow you to render a template.

---

Edit:

To access the 'position' variable from your view, define the view to take in an extra argument called position:

```
def view(self, request, initial={}, position=None):
    # The variable is now accessible by calling 'position' as a regular variable.
```

Remember, however, that you need to modify the URL routing rule as I've posted. Just change the first part to match the URL that I've given, eg:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^/new/?P(<position>\w+)/$', sfp.view),
    # ... etc.
)
```

I haven't tested this.

---

Overall, you've given us almost nothing to go on in this question. We want to help, but we need to see that you've bothered trying to make a URL routing rule and a view (rather than just asking for us to write them). All of this information is available in the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/) and the [official Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/). I recommend working through the tutorial first.

Comment: My question would..What do I need to validate in the request.get if the volunteer position is populated

Comment: I've already posted how to send the <position> argument to a view. I'm not sure what else you're after. Just modify your URL rule to match the first part of mine.

Comment: @paragan:How do I access the v.position in my view..? Should I use request.Get?